# DATABASE IN applescript/xcode

Tags: database, xcode, macos, youtube, applescript

so I watched this video on youtube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_PLHuhlAJU) on how to make a database. I rellay like the idea but I cant get it to work.

can anyone help me

P.S you can also tell me how to do this with xcode :-)

Comment: Building a database in Xcode? Good luck is what I wish you…

Comment: You don't specify how it's not working. Does it not compile? Does it not give the expected results? And if you're having trouble with provided AppleScript, diving into Xcode would probably be unwise at this point (although you can build AppleScript applications in Xcode). Just use Script Editor for now and try to get a piece of it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on Anne's comments, here's a much easier and more efficient database. At the top of the script you create your database. You just add and remove records from the database there. The rest of the code just searches the database and shows the results.

Note that one record in the database looks like this, and you just add and remove records as you expand your database.
{personName:"Sam Price", memberNumber:"1", phoneNumber:"123"}

```
set myDatabase to {{personName:"Sam Price", memberNumber:"1", phoneNumber:"123"}, {personName:"Dave Blogg", memberNumber:"2", phoneNumber:"1234"}, {personName:"jack tumb", memberNumber:"3", phoneNumber:"12345"}}

set x to text returned of (display dialog "Search for a member" default answer "ENTER THE NAME HERE!" buttons {"Search"} default button 1)

set foundRecord to missing value
repeat with aRecord in myDatabase
    ignoring white space
        ignoring case
            if (personName of aRecord) contains x then
                set foundRecord to aRecord
                exit repeat
            end if
        end ignoring
    end ignoring
end repeat

if foundRecord is missing value then
    set dialogText to "The person \"" & x & "\" cannot be found in the database!"
else
    set dialogText to (personName of foundRecord) & ", member number: " & (memberNumber of foundRecord) & ", phone number: " & (phoneNumber of foundRecord)
end if

display dialog dialogText buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The script discussed by this video is pasted in the video comment. It's not working properly because all new line characters are removed by Youtube. I changed the code to work as intended. Copy the code mentioned below to AppleScript Editor and hit run, it should work properly now.

Please note this is NO database. This script only gets your input and compares it one-by-one with some pre-defined values. When a mach occurs, it shows a dialog.

Note:
This code is very ugly. You better learn using loops and lists. This makes your code much more efficient.

```
set s to "sam price"
set d to "dave blogg"
set j to "jack tumb"
set m to "max dog"
set f to "fabio james"
set sa to "sara parker"
set o to "oliver jones"
set b to "bob samuel"
set x to text returned of (display dialog "Search for a member" default answer "ENTER THE NAME HERE!" buttons {"Search"} default button 1)
ignoring white space
    ignoring case
        if x contains s then
            display dialog "Sam Price,   member number: 1, phone number: 123" buttons {"OK"}
        end if
        if x contains d then
            display dialog "Dave Blogg, member number: 2, phone number: 1234" buttons {"OK"}
        end if
        if x contains j then
            display dialog "jack tumb,   member number: 3, phone number: 12345" buttons {"OK"}
        end if
        if x contains m then
            display dialog "Max Dog, member number: 4, phone number: 12345" buttons {"OK"}
        end if
        if x contains f then
            display dialog "Fabio James, member number: 5, phone number: 123456" buttons {"OK"}
        end if
        if x contains sa then
            display dialog "Sara Parker, member number: 6, phone number: 1234567" buttons {"OK"}
        end if
        if x contains o then
            display dialog "Oliver Jones, member number: 7, phone number: 12345678" buttons {"OK"}
        end if
        if x contains b then
            display dialog "Bob samuel, member number: 8,  phone number: 12345678" buttons {"OK"}
        end if
    end ignoring
end ignoring
```